# Elastica or ElasticSearch remove field from all documents

Tags: elasticsearch, field, elastica

I am wondering whether Elastica or ElasticSearch provides the ability to remove a single  field from all documents in a given index. I have found the correct way to do this in the REST API, but when trying to use it, it gives a syntax error.

I wrote

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/products/product/O2bMZYRek5/_update -d '{
"script": "ctx._source.remove("Color")"
}'
```

which returned

```
{"error":"JsonParseException[Unexpected character ('C' (code 67)): was expecting comma to separate OBJECT entries\n at [Source: [B@fddc294; line: 2, column: 32]]","status":500}
```

Comment: I found solution via bash
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/products/product/3zknrSRtMj/_update' -d '{
    "script" : "ctx._source.remove(\"Color\")"
}'

But now I need to realize it in Elastica lib

Comment: In your example the quote escaping is missing in `"Color"` (should be `\"Color\"`). It is present in the comment above, where you use `curl`.  That's why the parser complains about expecting a comma after `remove("`.

Answer (score 8):

you can do this via http api:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/goods_city_1/meirong/552899/_update' -d '{
    "script" : "ctx._source.remove(\"text\")"
}'
```

or you can do this via java api:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(String stringField : stringFields){
    sb.append("ctx._source.remove(\"").append(stringField).append("\");");
}
updateRequestBuilder.setScript(sb.toString());
```

I'v tried this, it gonna work. (at 0.90.2 at least.)

If you need it works for all doc in a index, you should put all this update action (or every 5000 action) into one BulkRequest, then throw it to sever.
Or maybe "elasticsearch-reindex"(https://github.com/karussell/elasticsearch-reindex) could help you, if you use alias to approach you data.

Comment: thank you, but I wrote same answer in comment of my question few month earlier